# String tokenizing to remove some data

Tags: java, string, string-parsing

I have a string like this:

```
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
```

The string might have more/less data also.
I need to remove `|` and get only numbers one by one.

Comment: Take a look at [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))]

Comment: 1) Do you have a question?  2)  [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Guava's [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) Rocks!

```
String input = "1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | | | | | | | |";
Iterable<String> entries = Splitter.on("|")
        .trimResults()
        .omitEmptyStrings()
        .split(input);
```

And if you really want to get fancy:

```
Iterable<Integer> ints = Iterables.transform(entries, 
     new Function<String, Integer>(){
        Integer apply(String input){
           return Integer.parseInt(input);
        }
 });
```

Although you definitely could use a regex method or String.split, I feel that using `Splitter` is less likely to be error-prone and is more readable and maintainable. You could argue that `String.split` might be more efficient but since you are going to have to do all the trimming and checking for empty strings anyway, I think it will probably even out.

One comment about `transform`, it does the calculation on an as-needed basis which can be great but also means that the transform may be done multiple times on the same element. Therefore I recommend something like this to perform all the calculations once.

```
Function<String, Integer> toInt = new Function...
Iterable<Integer> values = Iterables.transform(entries, toInt);
List<Integer> valueList = Lists.newArrayList(values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(myString);
sc.useDelimiter("|");
List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    if(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
    } else {
        sc.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
String str = "1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | | | | | | | |".replaceAll("\\|", "").replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like?

```
String s = "1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | | | | | | | |";
for(String n : s.split(" ?\\| ?")) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(n);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

`inputString.split("\\s*\\|\\s*")` will give you an array of the numbers as strings. Then you need to parse the numbers:

```
final List<Integer> ns = new ArrayList<>();
for (String n : input.split("\\s*\\|\\s*"))
  ns.add(Integer.parseInt(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split with the following regex (allows for extra spaces, tabs and empty buckets):

```
String input = "1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | | | | | | | | ";
String[] numbers = input.split("([\\s*\\|\\s*])+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

outputs:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 0):

Or with Java onboard methods:

```
String[] data="1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | | | | | | | |".split("|");

for(String elem:data){
   elem=elem.trim();
   if(elem.length()>0){
      // do someting
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string at its delimiter | and then parse the array.

Something like this should do:

```
String test = "|1|2|3";
String delimiter = "|";
String[] testArray = test.split(delimiter);
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (String string : testArray) {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
    values.add(number);
}
```